# Не удалось обнаружить компонент обработки изображений, который подходит для завершения данной операции. Почему?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void OpenNewFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp;*.vmv)|*.bmp;*.vmv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            filePath = ofd.FileName;
            var imageOperation = new ImageOperation();
            byte[] imageBytes = imageOperation.OpenFile(filePath);

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            bitmapImage.EndInit(); //исключение тут
        }
    }
```

---

```
public struct FileHeader
{
    public ushort bfType;
    public uint bfSize;
    public ushort bfReserved1;
    public ushort bfReserved2;
    public uint bfOffBits;
}
public struct InfoHeader
{
    public uint biSize;
    public int biWidth;
    public int biHeight;
    public ushort biPlanes;
    public ushort biBitCount;
    public uint biCompression;
    public uint biSizeImage;
    public int biXPelsPerMeter;
    public int biYPelsPerMeter;
    public uint biClrUsed;
    public uint biClrImportant;
}

public struct Color
{
    public byte blue;
    public byte green;
    public byte red;
}

internal class ImageOperation
{
    public Color[] srcImage;
    public Color[] dstImage;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int pixelSize;
    FileHeader fileHeader = new FileHeader();
    InfoHeader infoHeader = new InfoHeader();

    public byte[] OpenFile(string filepath)
    {
        using (var file = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var reader = new BinaryReader(file);
            fileHeader.bfType = reader.ReadUInt16();
            fileHeader.bfSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
            fileHeader.bfReserved1 = reader.ReadUInt16();
            fileHeader.bfReserved2 = reader.ReadUInt16();
            fileHeader.bfOffBits = reader.ReadUInt32();

            infoHeader.biSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
            infoHeader.biWidth = reader.ReadInt32();
            infoHeader.biHeight = reader.ReadInt32();
            infoHeader.biPlanes = reader.ReadUInt16();
            infoHeader.biBitCount = reader.ReadUInt16();
            infoHeader.biCompression = reader.ReadUInt32();
            infoHeader.biSizeImage = reader.ReadUInt32();
            infoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = reader.ReadInt32();
            infoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = reader.ReadInt32();
            infoHeader.biClrUsed = reader.ReadUInt32();
            infoHeader.biClrImportant = reader.ReadUInt32();

            width = infoHeader.biWidth;
            height = infoHeader.biHeight;

            srcImage = new Color[width * height];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    srcImage[i * width + j].blue = reader.ReadByte();
                    srcImage[i * width + j].green = reader.ReadByte();
                    srcImage[i * width + j].red = reader.ReadByte();
                }
            }
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[srcImage.Length * 3];
            int index = 0;

            foreach (Color color in srcImage)
            {
                byteArray[index++] = color.red;
                byteArray[index++] = color.green;
                byteArray[index++] = color.blue;
            }
            return byteArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Цель моей программы это открыть файл формата bmp(а в дальнейшем и моего кастомного формата) и вывести на экран, в чем моя ошибка, что я могу почитать на эту тему?

Comment: В том что `BitmapImage` кушает целиковый битмап вместе с заголовками, а вы ему голые пиксели подсунули. Отдайте весь файл целиком, и заработает. При чём не только битмап, оно и жпег и гиф и пнг и тифф съест.